# fill empty spaces before footer in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Problem with expanded and footer let me explain  a bit
I have this widget[Body mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgaQe.png)
I want to fill the empty spaces on different screen heights after product mobile and not after the footer which in this case put a background colored SizedBox after the footer if the widgets doesnot fill the screen height

what I tried
1- putting expanded to productsmobile will not make any effect because expanding already happens on the listview
2- removing expanding on listview will put an exception because you need to determine the size for scroablle widgets
3- taking the footer out of expanded will work but I dont want it to be sticked in the bottom of the screen
4- wrapping products mobile in sized box with mediaquery height percentage will make 2 scrolls 1 inside the other which will ruin Ux
5- putting some conditions to fill the space on certain screen heights is what am doing but not efficeint
bottom line: I want to fill empty sapce before the pagetailwidget and not after while keeping it inside the scroll bottom >>
I wish some one can help ... thank you all

Comment: Hi @ammar-mahmoud, you should put your code directly in your question and avoid external links. Additionally, consider adding a screenshot of your app.

Comment: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.